# How to create a function that inserts data into a block

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First can someone help me come up with a better title? I just don't know the correct terminology on this one.

Here is my code,

```
func loadPublicFeed() {

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("brackets").observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let bracketsSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for brackets in bracketsSnapshot {
                if let bracketsDict = brackets.value as? Dictionary <String, Any> {
                   let key = brackets.key as String
                    let post = BracketsPublicFeed(postKey:key, postData: bracketsDict)
                    self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)
                }
            }
        }
        self.stopRefresher()
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.watchlistClicked = false

    })
}
```

download data then do stuff. I want to take this function refactor it so I can just call the refactored function and add these

```
self.stopRefresher()
self.collectionView.reloadData()
self.watchlistClicked = false
```

into it.

It might look something like this,

```
func loadFeedTest() {
    fetchTest.loadPublicFeed(collectionView: self.collectionView, completionHandler: { () -> Void in
        self.stopRefresher()
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.watchlistClicked = false
      })
```

I have tried using a `completionHandler` something like `func loadPublicFeed(completionHandler: () -> Void)` then the code. I have done many variations of this. I feel like I might be on the right path but I just can't nail this down.

Comment: If you want to use a completion handler, you can use it. You can check my answer. For more information on closures in swift, I suggest you to go through this documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refactor your function in the following way:

```
func loadPublicFeed(collectionView: UICollectionView, completionHandler:() -> Void) {

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("brackets").observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let bracketsSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for brackets in bracketsSnapshot {
                if let bracketsDict = brackets.value as? Dictionary <String, Any> {
                    let key = brackets.key as String
                    let post = BracketsPublicFeed(postKey:key, postData: bracketsDict)
                    self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)
                }
            }
        }
        completionHandler();
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found out it was something else throwing it all off. Appreciate it!